# How to normalize data en-masse?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, normalization

## Goal:

Extract address fields from a users table into a separate addresses table
linked by foreign key.

I have created the structure below, and have millions of rows to deal with. I
need to do this once, but relatively quickly (ie, I can't loop over every row
in my Rails code)

The query below does work to extract the address fields into new rows in the
addresses table. But I can't figure out how to link the new rows back to the
users table that the data came out of.

## Structure:

### Before:

```
User
  login
  address_line_one
  address_line_two
  address_city
  address_state
  address_zip
```

### After:

```
User
  login
  address_id

Address
  id
  line_one
  line_two
  city
  state
  postal_code
  country
```

## What I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO addresses (line_one, line_two, city, state, postal_code, country)
SELECT address_line_one,
  address_line_two,
  address_city,
  address_state,
  address_zip AS zip,
  'US'
FROM users
WHERE
  address_line_one IS NOT NULL ||
  address_line_two IS NOT NULL ||
  address_city     IS NOT NULL ||
  address_state    IS NOT NULL ||
  address_zip      IS NOT NULL
```

## PROBLEM

I don't know how to get the `address_id` back into the users table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that `users.login` is unique.

- First, alter the users table to include an address_id column.
- Next, if you add a `addresses.login` column you would then be able to do the following query after the insert into addresses:

  ```
  UPDATE users, addresses SET users.address_id = addresses.address_id 
  WHERE users.login = addresses.login
  ```
- Finally drop the `addresses.login` column

An alternative would be to use an AFTER INSERT trigger on addresses to update the `users` table based on the unique address entries. Unfortunately, this assumes that all the fields of `addresses` combined represent a unique `users.login`, which for example would be invalid if a married couple each had logins but shared the same address.

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this, and it was the fastest of the options I had.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Modify the old user table and create the address_id as an auto_increment primary key field. Then select address_id in your query.

Also select login and address_id into the new user table.